# Camel RabbitMQ Default ConnectionFactory?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, apache-camel

I'm using Camel to consume and produce messages in RabbitMQ. Also, I'm working with Spring boot so I have created a [`ConnectionFactory`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/ConnectionFactory.html) bean with all the configuration I want.

That works great but I have to declare the name of the bean in every Endpoint string I create.

Is there a way to setup camel to use this specific bean by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [these](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-rabbitmq/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/rabbitmq/RabbitMQComponent.java#L62) source lines I don't think it is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

If you name your bean `rabbitConnectionFactory` then you don't have to specify this in every endpoint.

For example:

```
@Bean
    public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        factory.setPort(5672);
        factory.setUsername("guest");
        factory.setPassword("guest");
        return factory;
    }
```

And after that your rabbitmq URI is as simple as: `public static final String RABBIT_URI = "rabbitmq:%s?queue=%s&routingKey=%s&autoDelete=false";`